# do calculations for specific rows in R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I am so new to R, tried many things but did not work. My table looks like this:

```
data temp
11.01.15 11am 15 
11.01.15 12am 16
11.01.15 13am 14
12.01.15 11am 13
12.01.15 12am 11
12.01.15 13am 11
```

and it goes on for 5192 rows and many days, I have to calculate mean of the same day, the measurements are always done 3 times a day. So I need a loop that will calculate mean of values on rows 1-3, 4-6, 7-9 etc., and keep track of them and save in file.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have 3 observations, you can just calculate mean of `temp` over a module of 3. Assuming your data called `df`

```
tapply(df$temp, cumsum(seq(nrow(df)) %% 3 == 1L), mean)
#        1        2 
# 15.00000 11.66667
```

Another way is to convert `data` into a `Date` class an calculate mean over it. Here's an example using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, mean(temp), by = as.Date(data, "%d.%m.%y")]
#       as.Date       V1
# 1: 2015-01-11 15.00000
# 2: 2015-01-12 11.66667
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dplyr` package and its functions. I'm going to guess that you have a variable called "day" or "date" and another variable "x" that you want daily means on. The code:

```
group_by(data, day) %>% 
  summarize(meanX = mean(x))
```

will return a dataframe with a mean value of x for each day in the data set called `data`.

Comment: If the time stamp is part of the day variable it will run into problems. But `substr(day, 1, 8)` would take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lapply to do this

```
req.out = do.call(rbind, 
          lapply(split(data, f = data$date), 
          function(x){
          out = mean(x$measurement)
          }))
```

Where, data is your data frame containing date and the column (I called it as measurement above) for which you need to compute the mean.